# NSString sizeWithFont returns different value than before for a space character

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsstring, ios5

I use `UIStringDrawing sizeWithFont:` to determine the pixel width of a space character with a specific font. When I run my app in iOS 4 environment it returns 3 but when I run it on iOS 5 it returns 4. It behaves the same regardless if I use device or simulator.

Has anyone else experiences this?

Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem when I try to get a old project compatible with iOS5, In my opinion, the return value is not wrong, but in iOS5, the space width between two letter is no longer count in, so try to use more than one letter.
for me, I tried to use " " to replace other letters, now I use "  ", two spaces to calculate.

Comment: I ended up to check total length of string for each space I added and then matching that to the length of the string I was replacing with characters. Before I got the length of the string I was replacing and divided it by the length of a space character.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, looks like there is nothing to solve, but rather looks like simply that font changed from iOS4 to iOS5. Therefore I would suggest having something like this in your code:

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

And check the version to fix the gap.